# good looking alert in iphone app

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I am working on making my first iPhone app nicer :)
When an error occurs, I display it in a "basic" UIAlertView (blue background, a Cancel button).
I saw in several apps very good looking alerts when network errors occur (nice grey modal alert that only shows for a couple of seconds).
How can this be done ? Is that a particular configuration of UIAlertView ?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Luc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an alertview per se, but it is often used in conjunction with networking operations, as you mention.

https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Thanks, this is great stuff !!! I need to check if there is a kind of timing possible so error message (not necessarily linked to network operation) can appear for 2 seconds only.